# WCF Web API 0.6 - Returning List<T> in HttpResponseMessage throws an exception

Tags: wcf-web-api

I'm fairly new to the WCF Web API, I have a basic service going and trying to leverage the full power of using **HttpResponseMessage** as return type. I am trying to return a List and getting the following error around which I can't get around.

This is a very basic straight-up XML service.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

> Type
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entities.UploadedDocumentSegmentType]]'
>   cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the
>   DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you
>   want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type
>   is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.

Here's my service:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class DocumentService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetAllUploadableDocumentTypes")]
    public HttpResponseMessage<List<UploadedDocumentSegmentType>> GetAllUploadableDocumentTypes()
    {
       UploadedDocumentManager udm = new UploadedDocumentManager();
       return new HttpResponseMessage<List<UploadedDocumentSegmentType>>(udm.GetAllUploadableDocumentTypes());                                        
    }
}
```

The class UploadedDocumentSegmentType is defined as such:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class UploadedDocumentSegmentType
{
    public UploadedDocumentSegmentType();

    public int DocTracSchemaID { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And I tried this too:

```cs
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class UploadedDocumentSegmentType
{
    public UploadedDocumentSegmentType();

    [DataMember]
    public int DocTracSchemaID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

UDPATE: I used WCF REST Service Application Visual Studio template to create the service. I tried from scratch and change the return type on the sample WebGET method to WebResponseMessage and it would throw the same error there. So it's not my code, it's some configuration thing which for the life of me I can't figure out..

Comment: So it seems like the problem lies somewhere deeper, maybe some configuration setting? It blows up on anything returned in HttpResponseMessage. Even something like this produces the same error. I know I'm missing something really basic and stupid...


    '[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetTest2")]'
        public HttpResponseMessage<string> GetTest2()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage<string>("Test", HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

Comment: I don't think WCF REST Service Application VS template is actually compatible with WCF Web Api. By default WCF Web API returns JSON/XML and it does not use DataContractSerializer.

Comment: Could you point me to the right direction for the correct setup then? Thank you. I assumed this was the template was Web API because it did away with the SVC files... This is the one I used:http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd

Comment: There is a pretty good [tutorial on codeplex](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started:%20Building%20a%20simple%20web%20api) . From that page you can even download the complete solution. See link in the Code chapter.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to return a List<T>? Just return an array and it should be okay. I don't think the built-in JSON-Serializer knows how to handle a List<T>. A reasonable thing to not know how to do as a List<T> is "editable" via add/remove type calls.

Also, you don't need the datacontract/member attributes with wcf-web-api.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I figured I don't need the decorations. I've seen it work with List<T> in other projects, but they used probably a different JSON serializer. I am using a built-in XML Serializer actually. I will try an array as you suggest, but it seems like a workaround for me since the DLL I'm querying spits out a list<T> and the client needs a list<T> to work with..

Comment: I just tried casting into into an array and return that, I get the same exact error as list above. It seems to have the problem with the object itself..

Comment: I meant to say "Antony", sorry :)